# magento2 font weight error 700 after in line no 15

Tags: magento2

I have use magento2 in my local system. but error in frontend. default_head_blocks.xml file .  i have use font Noto+Serif:wght@400;700  .  but this line 700 & error . That is the Magento DOM validator throwing this error, The semicolon between the font weights is the issue. a semicolin is a valid query separator in a URL, in this case you have it incorrect.

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" src_type="url" />
```

so please help me.

```
enter code <?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <css src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src_type="url" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" src_type="url" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" src_type="url" />
    <css src="css/styles.css" defer="defer"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif:400,700" src_type="url" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
</page>
```